# Please explain bizarre behavior of .call(false)

Tags: javascript, boolean

```
> (function () { return this; }).call(false)
false

> !!(function () { return this; }).call(false)
true
```

In both Firefox 4 beta and Chrome latest.

It's like... when is a boolean, not a boolean?

Comment: so I guess the answer to my closing question, is when it's a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that when a primitive boolean is passed as the first argument to `call` or `apply`, it is auto-boxed into a `Boolean` object. This is clear in Firebug on Firefox 4:

```
>>> (function () { return this; }).call(false)
Boolean {}
```

In Chrome's inspector, it's initially confusing but a little probing reveals the truth:

```
>>> (function () { return this; }).call(false)
false
>>> typeof (function () { return this; }).call(false)
"object"
```

**All JavaScript objects are "truthy"**, even `new Boolean(false)` and `new Number(0)`. Therefore, using two negation operators (the `!!` trick) casts them to a `true` boolean.

Answer (score 4):

I found this line in the specification that explains the behavior.

```
3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the 
   ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).
```

Essentially the `false` value will be converted to a boolean object. The first application of the `!` operator will convert the object to `true` then invert to `false`. The second application of the `!` operator will invert `false` to `true`.

**Full Text**

```
10.4.3  Entering Function Code 

The following steps are performed when control enters the 
execution context for function code contained in function 
object F, a caller provided thisArg, and a caller provided argumentsList: 

1.  If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to  thisArg. 
2.  Else if thisArg is null or undefined, 
    set the ThisBinding to the global object.  
3.  Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the 
    ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg). 
4.  Else set the ThisBinding to thisArg. 
5.  Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment   
    passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal 
    property of F as the argument. 
6.  Set the LexicalEnvironment to  localEnv. 
7.  Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv. 
8.  Let code be the value of F‘s [[Code]] internal property.  
9.  Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code  
    code and argumentsList as described in
```

Comment: Oooh I am really tempted to go with this as the accepted answer since it references the spec... but ide's answer was pretty easy to follow, so I want to keep it at the top for anyone else that comes across this :).

Comment: @Domenic - Understandable, if they want to dig a bit deeper all they need to do is scroll down a bit.